# Mongodb :: Find data between two dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple use case. I want to extract data between two dates. Let say I have the only below document in my collection.

```
{
    
    "fromDate": "2022-07-07T00:00:00.000+00:00"
    "toDate": "2022-12-12T11:59:59.999+00:00",
    "promotionName": "Ticket discount"
}
```

I am applying below query it works fine as long as dates are exactly matched. But in case of dates between `fromDate` and `toDate` it gets failed.

```
busTicketPromotions.find({
    fromDate : {'$gte': new Date(fromDate)}, 
    toDate : {'$lte': new Date(toDate) }, 
});
```

Suppose if I pass `2022-07-07T00:00:00.000+00:00` in `fromDate` and `2022-12-12T11:59:59.999+00:00` in toDate, i get the result.

But if I pass `2022-08-08T00:00:00.000+00:00` in `fromDate` and `2022-11-11T11:59:59.999+00:00` in toDate it gets failed.

In simple words I want results equals to or between `fromDate` and `toDate`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The date type stored in the database server is of _UTC datetime._. You are probably using _local datetime_ from the client program.

Comment: @prasad_ can you please post the correct answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn the date into ISODate like this:

```
busTicketPromotions.find({
        day: {
            $gt: ISODate("2020-01-21"),
            $lt: ISODate("2020-01-24")
        }
    })
```